# With clang how can I find all variable names that are available at some source location?

Tags: clang, clang++

I have a project in which I use RecursiveASTVisitor to traverse the AST.
I would like to collect all variable names that are accessible at some source location. That would mean, if I want to insert a new variable at that location it must not conflict with any existing variable which is in the scope. For example:

```
const int N = 10;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    volatile int a = 2;
    if (a % 2) {
        int x = a / 2 + N;
        return x;
    }
    if (a % 3) {
        // here I cannot add new variable 'a', 'x' or 'N'
        int x = a / 3 + N;
        // here I cannot add new variable 'a', 'x' or 'N'
        return x;
    }
    // here I cannot add new variable 'a' or 'N'
    return 0;
}
```

And of course, there can be levels of nesting and many scopes.
I am not sure if there's anything built in clang for this, but I haven't been able to find it.